# Javascript reference

Tags: javascript

Javascript reference behaves differently for Objects. Please explain this below code.

In javascript variable assume x and y where x=5. I am assigning x to y and changing the value of y=6. x does not change x=5 still. But in javascript object assume x and y where x.a=5 if i am assigning x to y and changing in y to y.a=6, now x is also changed to x.a=6

Consider variables

```
var x,y;
x=5;
console.log(x);//x is 5
y=x;
y=6;
console.log(x);//x is still 5
console.log(y);//y is 6
```

Output

```
x:5
x:5
y:6
```

But in Object

```
var x={},y={};
x.a=5;
console.log(x);// x is {a:5}
x=y;
y.a=6;
console.log(x);// x is {a:6} changing y, x is also changed
console.log(y);// y is {y:6}
```

Output

```
x:{a:5}
x:{a:6}
y:{a:6}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y = x;
y = 6;
```

Here, you're assigning the value of `x` **to** `y` and then changing `y`. This doesn't change `x` because `x` is never assigned a new value.

```
var x = {}, y = {};
```

Here, you create two new objects and assign their addresses to `x`  and `y`. The two variables behave like pointers now and don't hold the object's values themselves but just its address. So, with `x.a = 5` you're not assigning 5 to `x` but to the new property `a` added to the object only referenced by `x`.

```
x = y;
y.a = 6;
```

And, here you actually overwrite that previous object's reference and make `x` point to the object referenced by `y` now. Since, `x` and `y` point to the same object now, the changes done through `y` reflect for `x` as well.

Comment: yes i understand this clarify me in real scenario i faced. I have two pages billing address and shipping address. I am getting the billing address details from user and saving it in 'billingAddress' object and in shipping address page i have a check box as **use billing address as shipping** if user check it and click next I am assigning 'shippingAddres=billingAddress' and redirect to address view page there is an option to edit the address. If user try to change in shipping address its getting reflected to billing address.

Comment: To solve this i used jquery extend... Please correct me if there is some solution to solve this

Comment: Don't assign `shippingAddres = billingAddress` but create a function like `copyAddress(sa, ba) { sa.flatNo = ba.flatNo; // and so on }` and copy all the properties. Using jQuery, it's even simpler if you use `$shippingAddres = $billingAddress.clone();`